# D3js Treemap redirect not working

Tags: csv, d3.js

I'm totally new to coding, I'm trying to add a redirect to a url when a node is clicked, after a couple of days of search here's what I've done

```
    var svg = d3.select("body")
   .style("width", w + "px")
.style("height", h + "px")
 .append("svg:svg")
//.attr("width", w)
//.attr("height", h)
.append("svg:g")
.attr("transform", "translate(.5,.5)")
.on("click",function(){ window.open("new.html");});
```

I'm working on https://gist.github.com/1446865
But it's not working can you help out ?
a small modification I have added the .on("click" on the SVG variable now it's working, now I need the URL to be the d.key but can't get it to work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work, I was adding the .on click on the SVG element when I had to add it to the .cell("rect")

here's the code 
https://gist.github.com/4589729

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the linking element with an `a` anchor tag as in [this example](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/linking/link01.svg).  The key element of this example is the following construct:

```
<svg>
  <a xlink:href="http://www.w3.org">
    <ellipse cx="2.5" cy="1.5" rx="2" ry="1" fill="red" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: Finally got it to work, I was adding the .on click on the SVG element when I had to add it to the .cell("rect")